# Rails build nested array from csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, csv

Happy Monday morning!

I am building a rails app that is going to process a CSV. Currently I have this in my mode...

```
 def self.import(file)
    student = Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = [] }
    student_start_dates = Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = [] }
    student_end_dates = Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = [] }
    student_last_attend_dates = Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = [] }
    student_final_grades = Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = [] }

    CSV.foreach(file.tempfile, :headers => true) do |row|
      #student[row["person_id"]] << row["start_date"]
      student_start_dates[row["person_id"]] << row["start_date"]
      student_end_dates[row["person_id"]] << row["end_date"]
      student_last_attend_dates[row["person_id"]] << row["last_attend_date"]
      student_final_grades[row["person_id"]] << row["final_grade"]
    end
```

...this gives me arrays that look like...

## end_dates

```
{"1159821"=>["8/19/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/27/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/19/2013"], "709267"=>["8/19/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/19/2013"], "1103305"=>["8/19/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/19/2013"]}
```

## start_dates

```
{"1159821"=>["12/14/2013", "12/14/2013", "12/14/2013", "12/14/2013", "12/14/2013", "12/14/2013", "12/14/2013"], "709267"=>["12/14/2013", "12/14/2013", "12/14/2013", "12/14/2013"]}
```

What I need is something that looks like...

```
{"1159821"=>"start_dates"=>["8/19/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/27/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/19/2013"], "end_dates"=>["8/19/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/19/2013"], "1103305"=>["8/19/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/19/2013", "8/19/2013"]}
```

So each students data is encapsulated into a single array that I can process for each student.

Comment: `1159821` is the student's id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would create a hash of students to their data that I think you should be able to use.  ie {"student_id1" => id1_data, "student_id2" => id2_data}

```
def self.import(file)
  students = Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = Hash.new {|inner_hsh, inner_key| inner_hsh[inner_key] = [] } }

  CSV.foreach(file.tempfile, :headers => true) do |row|
    students[row["person_id"]]["start_dates"] << row["start_date"]
    students[row["person_id"]]["end_dates"] << row["end_date"]
    students[row["person_id"]]["last_attend_dates"] << row["last_attend_date"]
    students[row["person_id"]]["final_grades"] << row["final_grade"]
  end
  students
end
```

Comment: Wow, that seems ugly...no? I mean you code is clean, but maybe it will be easier to process each array individually. I will consider re-factoring...thanx!

Comment: Actually after implementing this, it's actually not bad to manipulate. Thanx!